# Parallel web request

Tags: c#, multithreading, httpwebrequest

My C# application use some foreign web service, which based on Linux (this service use bash for prepare data and Apache for send it). When I make request in 1 thread, this service send response to me after ~10-15 seconds. When I use more then 1 thread, response time increases (40-70 seconds). I call to service owner and he told me, that his service working great with multithreading: *"I had just run 20 thread, which use this service and response time is 15 seconds!"*.

Can anybody tell me, what's wrong, why my very simple code:

```
        System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch myStopWatch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
            myStopWatch.Start();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Thread id = {0}; Action = {1}; Time = {2}; Url = {3}", System.Threading.Tasks.Task.CurrentId, 1, myStopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds, UrlToWebService));
//time is 0ms
            HttpWebRequest requestToDevice = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(UrlToWebService);
            requestToDevice.Proxy = null;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Thread id = {0}; Action = {1}; Time = {2}; Url = {3}", System.Threading.Tasks.Task.CurrentId, 2, myStopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds, UrlToWebService));
//time is ~45000ms
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)requestToDevice.GetResponse();
//time is ~45001ms
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Thread id = {0}; Action = {1}; Time = {2}; Url = {3}", System.Threading.Tasks.Task.CurrentId, 3, myStopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds, UrlToWebService));

            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
```

executed so slow?

Comment: Why are you writing to `Debug` when performance testing your code? I'd suggest using `StopWatch` when beginning and ending your calls. Also, you don't need extra threads for making async IO calls, that's redundant. Running code in multiple threads isn't a cure for everything, and there could be many reasons as to why this is slow. For starters, how many cores is the machine you're running this on have?

Comment: Yes, I use Debug.WriteLine only for performance testing. Ok, now I will try to use StopWatch. What do you mean about async IO calls?

Comment: An HTTP request is asynchronous by nature. You can make multiple calls without using threads. Look into the `HttpClient` class and read about it's `XXXAsync` methods.

Comment: I tryed to use HttpClient, but situation is the same! I can not understand why, but when I use my own Linux PC which is the same network with my work PC, and run next bush-script: 'cat argsForRequest.txt | while read args; do wget "http://ipOfService/requiredPhpScript.php?arg=$args" & done', then response time is about 10-15sec for all args. Can anybody tell me, what's wrong?